# How did Crain know Arthur Bishop was in Thailand?

Tags: plot-explanation, mechanic-resurrection

After his initial discovery by Crain at the beginning of *Mechanic: Resurrection*, Arthur Bishop escapes to Thailand which apparently is considered a "safe zone" for him. Less than 24 hours later, he is already being set up by Frank and Gina to lure him out.

How did Crain know where Bishop was, and how did he find him so fast?